# Can Jest be made to work with react-bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

Jest: 0.7.1
NPM: 3.3.6

It seems that automatic mocking is a problem.

If you unmock react-bootstrap it may be unmocked but some of its dependencies will be mocked.

This seems to specific to npm 3 which installs modules as siblings in the root.

There are are a couple of open issues on the react facebook github accounts:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5183
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/554

It appears there is currently no solution.

Does anyone know of a workaround?

Or - can anyone recommend any other test framework which will work with React TestUtils?

Comment: possible solution is to unmock everything that react depends on in unmockedModulePathPatterns. not a solution but i switched to use https://github.com/60frames/jestpack and this problem went away

Comment: It looks like ["deep unmock"](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/554#issuecomment-156523718) will be a solution. In the meantime I've just unmocked all of `node_modules`, because mostly I just want to mock my own stuff, and only `jest.mock()` specific external libraries that need to be faked.

Comment: @Aaron how did you unmocked all of `node_modules` ??

Comment: @YashikaGarg You can use [`unmockedModulePathPatterns`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react.html#setup)